# winbindd gss_init_sec_context failed with [Unspecified GSS failure]

Tags: centos7, winbind

Running CentOS7. Every hour I get the same error message. I have no problems authentication. I believe there is a Redhat solution but I don't have subscription.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2294131

Can someone tell me how to fix it? I have the latest update from the yum repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is adding to /etc/samba/smb.conf and restarting samba & winbind :

```
winbind rpc only = yes
```

Comment: That seem to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I managed to find out it is a winbindd bug.  Check out this link:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332089

What I can't figure out is if there is a newer version of winbindd that fixes this or if you have to down grade winbindd.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Follow the link to the Samba bug https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11852 for where it was fixed, then look for that bug in release notes to see the exact versions that have the fix.